# Adding Google smart lock to a website only

Tags: google-smartlockpasswords

Google Smart Lock on a website

I just visited Pinterest and it has a cool feature. Somehow when I visit the site Chrome can "see" that I have an account. And instead of passively waiting it informs me pro-actively: you do have an account here: would you like to login with 1 click? yes/No

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160273?hl=en

> **Question:** I see a lot of json code examples for apps. But how can we proactively add this to a website that a user has a stored uname/passwd for?

[image: Example image]

thanks, Sean

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an article describing how to add Smart Lock sign-in to your website: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/credential-management-api

Basically, add a bit of code to the (https) website like this (you can try it in the JavaScript console:

```
navigator.credentials.get({  
  password: true, // `true` to obtain password credentials  
}).then(function(cred) {  
  // continuation which submits the credential and signs the user in 
  ...
```

Here is a complete sample website: https://credential-management-sample.appspot.com/

Once the user has used this credential or you have saved it with `navigator.credentials.store()`, then in the future, it can retrieved automatically (without a user click).

For more information about this, check out [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnvUlGFb3GQ) from Google I/O (details on the credential management API start at about 8 minutes).

Comment: Users can also take advantage of those previously stored credentials via forms. Also, you can do similar thing on Android apps using the same shared password manager. Smart Lock for Password that is.